# How can I define dynamic keys in Swagger/Open API?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I am very new to swagger/openapi, I have been tasked with converting our current documenter to Openapi, I also have 2 parts to a similar question

with docblock it wasnt a problem, but I have an API that accepts a pattern as a key

e.g.
`'address_1/line_1'` or
`'address_2/line_1'`
it is set up this way because there are potentially up to 10 addresses (or more) that are sent over (I cannot change this format, it is what is given)

```
/**
 * @OA\Get(
 *     path="/api/storeAddress",
 *     @OA\Parameter(name="apikey",in="query",description="validation token"),
 *     @OA\Parameter(name="address_{????}/line_1",in="path",description="First Line of the address"),
 *     @OA\Parameter(name="address_{????}/line_2",in="path",description="Second Line of the address"),
* )
*/
```

I know that there are patterns available, but I dont know how to use them, basically I dont want to have to set up 50 potential parameters that wont get used.  Is there a half decent tutorial or page that can help me to define what these are supposed to be?

The second part is that an API key is sent via a query string and the rest is in JSON, am I right is describing the methods above (the apikey is a query string, whereas the rest is JSON)?